# Android List View with horizontal Layout but Scroll Vertically that replace text view

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist

How to create list view in android with horizontal Layout but Scroll Vertically that replace text view.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhDOi.jpg).

Actually I have a database and i am retrieving a column of words in String array. Now I want to print this String Array in sequence.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private EditText filterText;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    DbBackend dbBackend = new DbBackend(MainActivity.this);
    String[] terms = dbBackend.dictionaryWords();

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, terms);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // make Toast when click
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });`
```

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: Actually I want a List View in which First item should not break row other item should start from the end of previous item

Comment: Edit your question with the code, dont write it in the comments.

Comment: @Lepidopteron ok.

Comment: Kindly help me. Thank You so Much in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As per Android Documentation [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) is the new way to organize the items in listview and to be displayed horizontally

**Advantages**

1.Since by using Recyclerview Adapter, [ViewHolder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) is automatically implemented

2.Animation is easy to perform

3.Many more features

**More Information about RecyclerView:**

[1.grokkingandroid.com](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/)

[2.androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: It is possible with RecyclerView First item should not break row other item should start from the end of previous item

Comment: Can you Please give me some idea with Code? I am new to Android. i will be very Thankful to you

Comment: please follow androidhive link its easy fro you

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) or a RecyclerView with a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html). Have a look at the [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) to wrap the grid to the items width.